# Dynamics365 CRM - calling an Azure Function as webhook - challenge with text encoding

Tags: c#, azure-functions, webhooks, dynamics-365

I have an Azure Function (C#, .NET 8) that gets called from a cloud-based MS Dynamics365 CRM system via a webhook, when the name of a custom entity of ours changes in Dynamics CRM.

The call works just fine, my Azure function gets called, and the `POST` request is made. However, I have trouble reading out the contents of the `POST` body.

Since I'm in a predominantly German-speaking region, many of our names will contain umlauts - `ä ö ü Ä Ö Ü` - and those somehow get "mangled" when the webhook is called.

This is my Azure Function (simplified):

```
public class MyFunction
{
    [Function("MyFunction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        string postJson = await new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEndAsync();
 
        // handle the message that the entity has changed
    }
}
```

Somewhere in that JSON that I get is the new name of the entity - unfortunately, the umlauts aren't represented properly.

When I changed one entity's name to `Präsident 2024` in Dynamics, what I got in the JSON post body is:

```
PrÃ¤sident 2024
```

I tried just about any encoding that I could think of that would make sense - `Latin1`, `ASCII`, `UTF-32`, `Unicode` - but nothing worked - all of them return a "garbled" new name.

Why does this happen? What encoding or what approach do I need to take to get the **actual**, proper new name of my Dynamics entity?

**Update**

This is what my input looks like in MS Dynamics:

[image]

What get stored into DataVerse - still looking just fine to me:

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

For @PanagiotisKanavos

Using

```
string postJson = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

did not change a thing - still very much the same "mangling" (or double-encoding) of the German umlauts...

Here's the headers collection (slightly "tweaked" to protect the innocent - nothing seems to indicate anything to do with text encoding)...

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 4667
Content-Type: application/json
Expect: 100-continue
Host: myfunction-dev.azurewebsites.net
Max-Forwards: 9
x-functions-key: HLruyEwOS2wn_al_4a8bsqM25pMGR1FpP7vZh9V6t5G6AzFuEXhFYA==
x-ms-dynamics-organization: ********.crm4.dynamics.com
x-ms-dynamics-entity-name: ambcust_tag
x-ms-dynamics-request-name: Update
x-ms-correlation-request-id: c51275a3-985d-4b5b-adb2-a375db9ab3d3
x-arr-log-id: fea83f29-a979-4e37-a6c5-0cd0f6763ebe
client-ip: 20.50.69.12:61953
disguised-host: myfunction-dev.azurewebsites.net
x-site-deployment-id: myfunction-dev
was-default-hostname: myfunction-dev.azurewebsites.net
x-forwarded-proto: https
x-appservice-proto: https
x-arr-ssl: 2048|256|CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 05, O=Microsoft Corporation, C=US|CN=*.azurewebsites.net, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US
x-forwarded-tlsversion: 1.3
x-forwarded-for: 20.50.69.12:61953, 20.50.69.12
x-original-url: /api/HandleUpdate
x-waws-unencoded-url: /api/HandleUpdate
x-ms-coldstart: 1
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that they're not getting mangled before they get to you?

Comment: @madreflection: I can only see what my input is in MS Dynamics, and what gets saved into the MS Dynamics / Dataverse database - and that's correct / properly showing the data

Comment: I suspect that the web hook is mangling the text, especially if the column's type is `varchar` (but even if it is `nvarchar`). I worked with Dynamics GP several years ago and the database design was terrible. It was amazing that anything worked, and often didn't if it wasn't US, English, and Dollars.

Comment: I don't think issue is with the Function, because when I try sending data in body of as your Input and i result similar output.

Comment: @madreflection: thanks - but is there any way to "unmangle" it ? :-)

Comment: Input coming to function is mangled which resulting in mangled output

Comment: output https://i.imgur.com/3XGWBz0.png

Comment: Maybe. If that's the route you want to go, you would need to know how it's being mangled. You might be able to reverse-engineer it by analyzing the bytes, but by virtue of being mangled, you couldn't get 100% fidelity out of it.

Comment: The images show UTF8 text that was read as Latin1. The two bytes that represent `ä` appear as `Ã¤` in Latin1. Perhaps there's a missing charset on the Webhook side? What do the `req.Headers` contain? Also, why not use `ReadAsStringAsync`? The default according to the docs is UTF8 already.

Comment: Could the string be "double"-encoded? UTF8 incorrectly decoded as Latin1 that gets encoded to UTF8 again, resulting in separate UTF8 `Ã` and `¤` characters, ie 4 bytes. When your own code reads that UTF8 body, it retrieves those 4 bytes and produces the 2 characters. The real solution would be to find and remove the incorrect decoding. *Maybe*, just maybe, the quick&dirty fix could be to make the original call as Latin1 instead of UTF8. That's no solution for eg Scandinavian text (I work for a pretty big Swedish travel agency, so this is interesting)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I tried to see if there's anything I could influence about the text encoding when setting up the webhook in Dynamics - but alas, there's nothing, really - all I can set up is basically the URL (of my Azure function) to call. I'll check the other ideas and report back - thanks a heap !

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: using the `req.ReadAsStringAsync()` didn't help, unfortunately. Added the contents of the `req.Headers` to my question

Comment: `crm4.dynamics.com` so this is D365 *CRM*, or however it's called now? D365 is an umbrella term covering many products, some unrelated to each other, eg D365 For Finance which started as Axapta. If any code is on Github, you may be able to search for clues.

Comment: Is the webhook called by an on-prem server? Perhaps there's a hard-coded CultureInfo, encoding or locale setting somewhere? Somehow the code is reading UTF8 bytes, treating them as Latin1 and then sending them as JSON with a proper UTF8 encoding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: no, it's a Dynamics365 CRM instance in the Microsoft cloud, calling an Azure Function in the Microsoft cloud ..... go figure ....

Comment: This sounds like either a configuration or product bug. Dynamics CRM is used all over the world though, so I doubt this is a CRM bug. If the webhook is rarely used, this could be a bug but I doubt this as well. The real solution is to contact support (or look over all localization settings again - someone may have set Latin1 to ensure they can read local data files). You'll waste an expensive support case but any quick fixes will break once the real problem is solved

Comment: A quick fix would be to try and reverse the encoding - Read the text as UTF8 as you do now to get the `Ã` and `¤` characters , encode it as Latin1 to get the single bytes these represent, then decode again as UTF8 to get `ä`

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to @madreflection.

As I said in the comment issue is not related to function. Input is getting changed before coming to function body.

##### My code;

```cs
       [Function("Function1")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
       {
           _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
           string postJson = await new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEndAsync();

           string decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postJson));

           return new OkObjectResult($"{decoded}");
```

##### Input:

```
Präsident
```

#### `OUTPUT`:

```
Präsident
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's my gut feeling, too - I use Azure Functions a lot, and so far, I never had any trouble with text encoding of German special characters. But getting the data from Dynamics via a Webhook is a new approach for me - most likely , this is the cause of this problem - but I just can't seem to find any indication as to how to influence/fix the problem ...